# Is it correct to use GROUP BY along with an aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I read that it is not correct to use an aggregate function along with the `GROUP BY` clause.
Below are some points which I found in the book.

> When using the GROUP BY clause with a SELECT statement:
>
> • The SELECT’s columnlist must include a combination of column names and aggregate functions.
>
> • The GROUP BY clause’s columnlist must include all nonaggregate function columns specified in
> the SELECT’s columnlist. If required, you could also group by any aggregate function columns that
> appear in the SELECT’s columnlist.
>
> • The GROUP BY clause columnlist can include any columns from the tables in the FROM clause of the
> SELECT statement, even if they do not appear in the SELECT’s columnlist.

However, when I use the `GROUP BY` clause along with an aggregate function (I used MySQL), there is no error generated and I get the answer expected. Why is this?

As an example see this code:

`SELECT MONTHS * SALARY FROM EMPLOYEE GROUP BY MONTHS * SALARY;`

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE GROUP BY COUNT(*);`

I get no error generated. I find the points given in the book more logical because at the beginning, the table does not have a column `MONTHS * SALARY`. So how does this happen? And why does this observation contradict with the points given in the book?

Comment: These formulations are inaccurate/simplified. Each time `column name` term used the term `an expression` must be used. The expression may be single column or complex expression which uses column(s) and literals (except literals only expressions which are non-effecting constants). So in 1st query there is only one expression which uses 2 columns, and it is used in both output list and grouping expression. 2nd query is synthactically wrong and must produce `Can't group on 'COUNT(*)'` error message.

Comment: Statement 3 effectively contradicts Statement 1. I'd say statement 3 is essentially true, and statement 1 is false, although it normally would contain both column names and aggregate functions.